# Material UI: Delay issue when passing large dataset to Autocomplete component in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I am using the Autocomplete component from Material-UI in my React application. When trying to pass a large dataset of approximately 10,000 items as a prop to the Autocomplete component, I am experiencing a significant delay of around 5 seconds before the dropdown menu renders with the expected data.

I have implemented the Autocomplete component following the documentation provided by Material-UI at https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#checkboxes.

Here's the relevant code snippet for reference:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckBoxOutlineBlank';
import CheckBoxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckBox';

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;

type AutoSelectDropdownProps = {
    dropdownData?: any,
    isMultiple?: boolean,
    onChange?: any
    defaultvalue?: any,
    valueField?: string
    displayField?: string,
}

export function AutoCompleteDropDown(props: AutoSelectDropdownProps) {

    let newObj = [...props.dropdownData];

    const loadValues = (event: any, values: any) => {
        const target = {
          value: [],
          name: undefined
        };

        if (values && values.length > 0) {
          target.value = values.map((item: any) => item[props.valueField || 'value']);
        }

      props.onChange({target});

    }


  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      options={newObj}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.value}
      limitTags={2}
      onChange={loadValues}
      defaultValue={
        props.dropdownData.filter((item: any) => {
          return props.defaultvalue.includes(item[props.valueField || 'value']);
        })
      }
      renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
        <li {...props}>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            checked={selected}
            />
          {option.value}
        </li>
      )}
      size="small"
      sx={{ minWidth: 180, width: '100%', mt: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} size='small' />
      )}
    />
  );
}


export default AutoCompleteDropDown;
```

Comment: no, can you please share the link if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use custom filters in Material-UI Autocomplete component to limit  count of large dataset.

For example:

```
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
  ignoreCase: true,
  matchFrom: "start",
  limit: 10,
});

<Autocomplete
  ...
  filterOptions={filterOptions}
  ...
/>;
```

To learn more, see [Material-UI-Custom-Filter](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#custom-filter).

If you have a large amount of data, please see [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#search-as-you-type).

Comment: can we do it using lodash?

Comment: What do you mean? I can't understand. Autocomplete supports filtering automatically. please let me know

Comment: filterOptions is working fine but instead of "filterOptions" can we do it using, debounce?

Comment: I don't think you need to use debounce for this case. the Autocomplete component already handles the filtering logic internally, and you can use the filterOptions prop to customize it. So you mean if you can't use filteroption?

Comment: Yes, you are right filter-options is working for me, but let's say in the case of larger data (ex: 10,000+). Do you think It's a good idea to store data in memory and access it every time we select any dropdown field? That's why was thinking to bring Debounce.

Comment: I understand you. if so, please see updated answer. there is how to use debouncing and fetching in that case.